# How to find the number of times a string is found in a saved html file?

Tags: python, string, nlp, spacy

I have a saved html file from which I am trying to find the number of times a particular string is found. For example:

```
string= 'Beautiful days'
text = "those beautiful days were unforgettable. I wish every day was a beautiful day"
```

output expected = 2 (beautiful days, beautiful day"

tried the following below:
I tried using spacy but could not do it. can anyone tell me the logic for this?

Comment: `beautiful days` and `beautiful day` are not the same.

Comment: @DirtyBit I am trying to find both closest and exact match

Comment: cool. you can use `lower()` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
import re

with open("count_string_in_file.txt") as f:
    html = f.read()

to_match = "beautiful day"
matches = re.findall(to_match, html, re.IGNORECASE)
print(len(matches), matches)
# 2 ['beautiful day', 'beautiful day']
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/2c70ecbc5e)

Answer (score 0):

You can use stemmer. It might be overkill but it will find the closest words as well

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 

ps = PorterStemmer() 

sentence = "those beautiful days were unforgettable. I wish every day was a beautiful day"
words = word_tokenize(sentence) 
sentence = ""
for w in words: 
    sentence += (ps.stem(w.lower()) + " ")
query = 'Beautiful days' 
words = word_tokenize(query) 
query = ""
for w in words: 
    query += (ps.stem(w.lower()) + " ")
print(sentence)
print(query)
print(sentence.count(query))
```

```
those beauti day were unforgett . i wish everi day wa a beauti day 
beauti day 
2
```